# FusedLocationProviderClient not working in Android 10

Tags: android, location, android-gps, fusedlocationproviderapi

I have used `FusedLocationProviderClient` to retrieve a one-time location with the following request.

```
LocationRequest request = new LocationRequest();
request.setInterval(1000);
request.setNumUpdates(1);
request.setMaxWaitTime(2500);
request.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
```

I have also applied setting resolution to enable GPS. Everything working fine with normal steps.

But, When I apply the following steps, it is not working or taking more than 3 minute to give the location.

1. Location is off and click on "No thanks" button on GPS popup first time.
2. Then again click on "Ok" button on GPS Popup.
3. After that, I am requesting the location. But not getting location or some times it gives after 3-5 minutes.

**Edit**

Here is my sample code :- https://pastebin.com/zxVCMCPn

Comment: can you share some code on how you're making request? By looking at just request, it's not straightforward to find issue.

Comment: @MaulikHirani wait I am sending sample code.

Comment: @MaulikHirani check above code.

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya, thanks for a good code.

Answer (score 1):

This is how im getting location and its works fine.

```
   //declare them universally //before on create
   LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    LocationCallback mLocationCallback;
 FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;



   private void realLocation (){
        if(liveloction){

            locationrequestfunct();
            if(mLocationPermissionGranted){
                fusedLocationProviderClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }

        }

    }

    private void locationrequestfunct(){
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(30000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(10000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_LOW_POWER);
    }
```

and this should be in oncreate
//init fouced location //both of these should be on create,

```
 fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

//the call back will not work if is not in on create
mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {


    }
};
```

Comment: Have you checked in android 10 with above steps?

Comment: yes it works totally fine with android 10, i test this on real device Samsung A30s (android100. this code gives me continues location unless i call  fusedLocationProviderClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);